# Not getting the correct domain for an ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, regions

I want to find the domain of the the ODE $y\,= (y \operatorname{Ln} (y))/x$  and visualize it.

```
A = FunctionDomain[(y Log[y])/x, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> y > 0 && x != 0
> ```

```
B = FunctionDomain[x/(y Log[y]), {x, y}]
```

> ```
> y > 0 && Log[y] != 0
> ```

```
Dom = Union[A, B]
```

> ```
> y > 0 && x != 0 && Log[y] != 0
> ```

Plotting the domain with

```
RegionPlot[Dom, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

gives me

[image: graph]

but this is not correct.

Comment: @kgir  Your answer looked correct to me.

Comment: It's not , you need to remove from graph , point (0,1) , because in that point function is undefinited , 0/0 ..

Comment: @kgir 's plot accurately represents `y > 0 && x != 0 && Log[y] != 0`, which is what you asked for.

Comment: How do you want mathematica to remove a SINGLE point (one pixel)? from a plot or region? How should the plot look like?

Comment: bbgodfrey: yea , region is "y > 0 && x != 0 && Log[y] != 0" , but that region is equal to "y>0 , x!=0 , y!=1" so point (0,1) doesnt bellow that region . 

Naser : I asked, probably there is some option , for example on graph can look like very small point, or small "x" on that place ..

Comment: Naser: If is that corect what you tell , how then ListPlot exist ? It also give points on graph ?  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html

Comment: @Милош Вучковић In the documentation of `RegionPlot` you might read "RegionPlot will only visualize two-dimensional regions". No points, no lines!

Comment: Ok , if do not need use RegionPlot , i asked what to use to get Visual Presentation of my d.e Domain ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point `{0,1}` is not a member of the domain you computed, but of course you can't see that it is omitted in the region plot you generate. The omission of a single point simply won't show up in such a plot.

To confirm that `{0,1}` isn't in the domain, consider the following.

```
A = FunctionDomain[(y Log[y])/x, {x, y}];
B = FunctionDomain[x/(y Log[y]), {x, y}];
dom = Union[A, B];
RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[dom, {x, y}], {0, 1}]
```

> `False`